# scipy adding a custom linkage function

Tags: python, scipy, customization, cluster-analysis, linkage

I am trying to add a custom linkage function to the hierarchical clustering in SciPy. I can't seem to access the implementation which redirects to **_hierarchy.linkage(y, n, method_code)** in **.so** compiled file.

Any idea on how to go further in a clean way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the sklearn *source* code.

Modify it, then compile the Cython code to get a new .so file.

Using pure Python code would be too slow, it is necessary to compile this into C. Cython is very similar to Python, but with static typing and compiled to native code.